# VS Code: keybinding to move cursor to next occurrence of word under cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code

If my cursor is under word `foo` in text, is there a keybinding in VS Code that will move the cursor to the next occurrence of the word `foo` in the text?

(I had this feature in my previous IDE, IntelliJ IDEA. It was called [Find Word at Caret](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/finding-word-at-caret.html))

Comment: You should look at `F7: go to next Symbol Highlight`.  In many cases it will do what you want.

Comment: `Shift+F7` to go back

Answer (score 55):

To find the word the cursor is at, do the following:

Use `Ctrl+F` keyboard shortcut then press `Enter`.
To navigate between the occurrences of the word at caret
Press `F3` to go to the next occurrence.
Press `Shift+F3` to go to the previous occurrence.

---

Or just Press `Ctrl+F3`
and `Ctrl+Shift+F3`,

You may see/change that shortcuts in the editor by going to the menu under File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts. (Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts on Mac)
then search for `find selection`, see:
[image]

---

See [Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings), and **Keyboard shortcuts** cheat sheet in PDF file format for [Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf)
, [macOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf), and
[Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf).

---

[Multiple selections (multi-cursor)](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor)

`Ctrl+D` selects the word at the cursor, or the next occurrence of the current selection.
Press `Ctrl+D` again for Multiple selections or you may just Press `F3` to go to the next occurrence. Press `Shift+F3` to go to the previous occurrence.

---

And if you enjoy vim, you may install [VSCodeVim](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) extension,
which is a Visual Studio Code extension that enables Vim keybindings, and like vim:
Press `*` to search for the next occurrence.

Comment: Thank you, A.R, but I was looking for a more convenient shortcut. The Find Word At Caret functionality should, with a single keybinding, allow me to scan forward or backward for the word under caret.

Comment: I recommend Vim extension, it is just one key you need: `*`

Comment: also you may press  `Ctrl+F3`

Comment: See New Edit. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ctrl + F3 / Ctrl + Shift + F3.

Comment: Ctrl+F and then F3 is what I would like Ctrl+F3 to do. But there seems to be no way to do it. In IntelliJ the command is called "Next Occurrence of the Word at Caret". I miss it. Similarly, it'd be great to press Ctrl+R and it will open the Find/Replace box with the word at the caret so that I can quickly replace it.

Answer (score 7):

I've created this extension which reimplements the [IntelliJ Find Word At Caret](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-word-at-caret.html) functionality in VS Code:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mksafi.find-word-at-cursor

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change the text in the Find toolbar, if it's showing.

Answer (score 7):

On Mac:

For next occurrence: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>

For previous occurrence: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>

Comment: This only works if there's no current value in the Find input field.
This does not replace the current value in the Find input field.
See my answer for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Use the vim extension**

You can install from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) or do a search on "vim" in the extensions marketplace

Once installed you just highlight the word and then use the command `gb`

Comment: Very interesting, there is no documentation about `gb` anywhere. And it doesn't work in vscode neovim. I'm pretty confused about this hidden gem.

Comment: @Sem I don't use neovim.  you can find the command on this [page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim)

Answer (score 1):

There is another method to go to next/previous occurrence. You can ctrl+click on the word, to list all occurrences in a nice pop up.

[image]

Why this method? When using code folding to hide sections of code. If the next occurence is inside a hidden code block, the block will be expanded, if you go to next occurrence using (ctrl+F find) or (ctrl+d select next).

With ctrl+click, only a particular block which I double click at (2), will be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

The closest feature I could find is as of version 1.39.1 of VS Code ([Source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/dfa1b212462b34f2713376fa168b545388f60dd4)), "Go to Next Symbol Highlight" was added with the default shortcut `F7` for the next highlight and `Shift+F7` for the previous highlight.

Unfortunately this only works when the keywords are highlighted.

The action can be referenced with `editor.action.wordHighlight.next` or `editor.action.wordHighlight.prev`.

Answer (score 0):

I use intellij as well and am setting up vs code to be as similar as possible. The plugin I have found to solve this problem is

[Select Next Occurrence](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thomaswelen.SelectNextOccurrence)

Comment: Is that extension for Visual Studio Code?  Or Visual Studio only?

Answer (score 0):

I use autohotkey to achieve this. eg. (ALT+w) will send (F7), which is the default vscode shortcut for going to the next occurrence.

```
; vscode
#IfWinActive ahk_exe Code.exe

    SetTitleMatchMode 2

    ; delete line
    Capslock & d:: Send ^+k

    ; select next/previous 
    !q:: Send +{F7}
    !w:: Send {F7}

    ; go to next/previous cursor position
    !e:: Send !{left}
    !r:: Send !{right}

#IfWinActive
```

Why use autohotkey? If I wish to remap alt+r, I don't have to remove ALL existing conflicts from the vscode's keyboard settings first.

Plus, it's easier to transfer the settings over to a friend's computer, without overwriting their own keyboard shortcuts.

You might find the other shortcuts related to cursor navigation useful. I use these so many times, that it's worth remapping them to an ergonomic position.

Comment: Only works on Windows.