# Replace everything after a current occurrence in VS Code find/replace

Tags: visual-studio-code, replace

I have a json of the following format:

```json
[
  {
    "MyField": "Hello World",
    "Year": 2020
  },
  {
    "MyField": "foo bar",
    "Year": 2020
  },
  {
    "MyField": "mystring1",
    "Year": 2020
  }
]
```

The value `2020` occurs 3 times above. In VS Code find/replace (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>), is there a way (perhaps using regex?) to only replace everything after a certain occurrence of a value, using the `Replace All` action? For example, I would like to replace everything after the 2nd occurrence of `2020` with `2021`, while leaving the first occurrence intact.

Desired output:

```json
[
  {
    "MyField": "Hello World",
    "Year": 2020
  },
  {
    "MyField": "foo bar",
    "Year": 2021
  },
  {
    "MyField": "mystring1",
    "Year": 2021
  }
]
```

Comment: select the range where you want to replace, press Ctrl+F and then check button **Find in Selection**, then type what you want to Find and Replace, then press **Replace All**

Comment: propose to dup-close to either https://stackoverflow.com/q/45901507/11107541 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/44335619/11107541

Comment: Proposal denied. Not a dup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see this extension: [select-to-eof](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=awtnb.select-to-eof) that makes what you want to do easy.

1. Select the first occurrence you want included.
2. Trigger the command `select-to-eof: seed`.
3. All remaining matches are selected, you can type your replacement.

[image: select to end of file demo]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can search and replace with this kind of logic
directly inside *Visual Studio Code*. Using a regular expression
with a positive lookbehind would be a way to achieve it, but for
your simple case, you can select the last part of your file and
only search and replace in the selection :

[image]

#### On some regex engines, you can use a lookbehind

In the latest *JavaScript* engines (the case in my *Chrome*), you
are allowed to use a variable length lookbehind. A demo here:

https://regex101.com/r/O1iOhc/1

The idea is to search for `"year": 2020` only if it is preceded by
`"year": 2020` and anything else.

In *Visual Studio Code*, I didn't find a way to enable the `s` flag
so that the `.` matches also new lines. But the `.` (for "*any char*")
can be replaced by `[\w\W]`, leading to this search pattern :

```
(?<="Year": 2020[\w\W]*?)"Year": 2020
```

And then replace it by `"Year": 2021`

Thanks to @Mark's comment and
[this question about *VS Code*'s regex engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179046/what-flavor-of-regex-does-visual-studio-code-use),
we can see that fixed-length lookbehinds are only limited to search
across files, because it's using *ripgrep* in the background, which
is based on *Rust* or *PCRE2* (depending on your settings). But
**the file editor window will let you use non-fixed-length lookbehinds**, because it is using *JavaScript*, which is continuously
improving its regex engine.

#### For elaborated search and replacements : program it!

To do more sophisticated search and replacements, you'll need to do
a bit of programming. Typically, in *JavaScript*, you can use a
callback function instead of a replacement string. This way, you
can use a counter or do anything complicated for the replacement.

Here, I captured the field name and the separator in a first capturing
group and any year (digits) in a second capturing group. The callback
function will receive the full match as the first argument and then
the capturing groups as other arguments. My logic is to take the
current year and increment it by one, but only for occurrences
higher than 1. Of course, the mathematical operation of year
increment is just here as an example, to show you what it can bring
compared to an IDE.

```js
const json = `[
  {
    "MyField": "Hello World",
    "Year": 2020
  },
  {
    "MyField": "foo bar",
    "Year": 2020
  },
  {
    "MyField": "mystring1",
    "Year": 2020
  }
]
`;

// Regular expression with a capturing group for the field name, some
// optional spaces, the double-point and a second capturing group for
// the numeric value.
const regex = /(?<name>"Year"\s*:\s*)(?<value>\d+)/g;

let occurrence = 1;

// Use a callback function for the replacement value so that we
// can do some more elaborated logic.
const result = json.replace(regex, (fullMatch, name, value) => {
  if (occurrence++ > 1) {
    let year = parseInt(value);
    return name + (String)(year + 1);
  } else {
    return fullMatch;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: "unfortunately this will only work if the lookbehind has a fixed length".  That is not true for the Find in a file widget (the one you show).  That IS true for Search across files though.  There is some persistent misinformation on this on SO.

Comment: @Mark: Well, I tested it on my Mac yesterday and I didn't manage to make it work (that's why I wrote it and put the example on *regex101*). But effectively, I now see why! I wanted to replace the `.*?` by `[\s\S]*?` as I didn't find how to enable the `s` flag so that `.` matches new lines. But it only works with `(?<="Year": 2020[\w\W]*?)"Year": 2020`. Do you know why? If you know a way to use inline flags, I would also be interested.

Answer (score 1):

This perl script will do it. On a Mac or Linux, you get perl out of the box. With windows, Git Bash can provide it.

```
#!/opt/homebrew/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my $seen = 0;
while(my $line = <>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /(\"Year\":)\s+2020/) {
        if ($seen > 0) {
            my $blah = "$1 2021";
            $line =~ s{$1\s+2020}{$blah}e;
        }
        $seen = 1;
    }
    print $line . "\n";
}
```